# powershell won't remove multiple directories

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am relatively new to power-shell. I can delete folders individually, but I can't delete multiple folders, nor can I use a loop.

`rmdir 'folder 1' -Recurse -Force` in the folder works.

`rmdir 'folder 1' 'folder 2' -Recurse -Force` does not.

these also don't work.

```
$filenames = Get-Content -Path ".\delete.txt"
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "./$file"
}
```

```
$filenames = Get-Content -Path ".\delete.txt"
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
Remove-Item "./$file" -Force -Recurse -Path
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use comma (,) if you have two or more folders to remove.

```
Remove-Item -Path "folder 1", "folder 2" -Recurse -Force
```

The first code block with the foreach loop that you provided is working fine. Just make sure that the files in delete.txt are all in the current directory. Otherwise, just use full paths in delete.txt and replace `"./$file"` to `$file`.

Comment: It does not work if the folder paths are stored in variables.

Comment: Store your folder paths in an array variable like this `$filenames = ("C:\folder1", "C:\folder2")`. Then you can use the for each loop block or this one-line answer. `Remove-Item -Path $filenames -Recurse -Force`